# Removing Index.php on OSX Yosemite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

CodeIgniter newbie here.

I am trying to get the index.php file removed from the url. Here what I have done so far.

I have created an .htaccess file in the root at the same level as application and have this in the file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have set

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I get a 404 not found error with this setup.

When I uncomment Include `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in the `httpd.conf` file I get 403 Forbidden.

I assume that the url after removing the index.cfm would be `localhost/sites/xxxx/blog`

Can anyone help?  I have scoured the internet trying various combinations of things and I am tired.  I assume this is a OSX thing.

Comment: Try adding 'AllowOverrire all' in your `httpd-vhosts.conf` see this link http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: I have not changed the httpd-vhosts.conf file so where would I put it in that file?

Comment: First it is nothing with OS because website is running on server beside the OS. What is CI root directory in that link: is that `xxxx`?

Comment: Yes the xxxx is the CI root.  So under that is application and so forth.  What I was thinking about the OS is if there is something not turned on in OSX like in linux.

Comment: You put that inside the <VirtualHost *> on a separate line just like DocumentRoot. 
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example2
ServerName www.example.org

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
[example](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)

Comment: Having an exact same issue. Any leads to this?